# installed shim-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu, 21.04

I'm trying to install kubuntu 21.04 with windows on the same drive, I shrinked my D: drive for 80GB, installed iso from official site and wrote it to my usb drive with rufus.
When I got to disk setup page I selected this 80GB unallocated storage as root ('/') and after everything went ok I got popup with this text 'installed shim-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1'.
After this I did check for bad blocks on usb drive and partition on the drive and results showed no issues with them
What's wrong?

Comment: I checked hash for iso file too

Comment: Can you reboot your system and go back into the Kubuntu Live instance, but just "Try Kubuntu" (close out of the installer if it autostarts, it'll drop you to a desktop).  Open the Terminal application (I forget what it's called in Kubuntu), and run `sudo -E calamares --debug`.  When it errors out, please copy and paste the entire run log of Calamares (the installer) from the command line into your question as an edit, because that'll give us more information needed to debug what actually went wrong.

Comment: @ThomasWard live cd version isn't really working, i always get graphics bugs and no matter how much i wait it could not load properly

Comment: If you can't get to the Live environment, then what ISO are you using and how are you installing Kubuntu?  The Kubuntu live CD would be needed to install Kubuntu as I currently understand the Kubuntu ISOs

Comment: @ThomasWard from official website, checked the hash of it after error occured

Comment: I got the same error when I try to install 21.10 beta as well.  Live CD didn't boot